# Tolerance limit (interval) in python

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval, python

I am trying to calculate the tolerance limit (interval) in python. As a reminder, the tolerance limits are:

$$
\bar{x} \pm k s
$$

where $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean and $s$ is the sample standard deviation. The book I am reading uses a table to get $k$, but I would like to calculate $k$ myself in python. I found the formula for $k$ on page 12 in [this document](https://math.usu.edu/jrstevens/biostat/Tolerance.pdf) which suggests:

[image]

I am familiar with `scipy.stats` package but I cannot figure out how to get $k$ - I've tried a few permutations. For example:

```
from scipy import stats as s
import numpy as np

n = 30
p = 0.995
z = s.norm.ppf((1-p)/2)

g = 0.99
c = s.chi2.ppf(g, df=n-1)
k = z * np.sqrt(((n-1)*(1 + 1/n))/c * (1 + (n-3 - c)/(2*(n+1)**2)))
print(k)
```

The statistical table for $k$ from the book is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the quantiles are not being calculated correctly.  This isn't your fault:  the presentation is not clear about this, and fails to provide a numeric example of the formula against which you can confirm the calculation.

As used in the presentation, the quantity $z_{(1-p)/2}$ refers to a number such that $$\Pr[Z > z_{(1-p)/2}] = \frac{1-p}{2}.$$  Note the direction of the inequality:  the author is using an upper quantile, rather than a lower one.  In Python, `norm.ppf` calculates $\Pr[Z \le z_{(1-p)/2}]$.  So to compensate, you can simply write `z = -s.norm.ppf((1-p)/2)` or equivalently, `z = s.norm.ppf((1+p)/2)`.

The other problem you are having is that you are using $g = 0.99$ when the formula is expecting $g = 0.01$.  In other words, you should either write `c = s.chi2.ppf(1-g, df=n-1)`, or you should define `g = 0.01`.  Again, this is the author's sloppiness and is essentially the same problem as above:  not specifying how the quantile is to be calculated.

Here is my calculation for $n = 30$, $p = 0.995$, $g = 0.99$ (using your inputs).  I get $$z = 2.80703, \quad c = 14.2565, \quad k = 4.08316.$$

Comment: But the notation $z_{\alpha}$ almost always refers to an upper quantile.

Comment: @StubbornAtom That may be the case, but "almost always" is not "always."  I have seen authors use $z_\alpha^*$, for example.  And I have (rarely) seen other authors use $z_{1-\alpha}$.  The issue here is that there should be no room for interpretation as this leads to confusion, as in the OP's example.

Comment: On the contrary I am used to seeing $z_{\alpha},\chi^2_{n,\alpha}$ etc. always as upper quantiles.

Comment: @heropup I am not getting the correct numbers though. See the table that I added which is from the book.

Comment: @StubbornAtom As I have previously stated, this is not always the case, and just because you are used to seeing the notation used in a particular way does not make it unambiguous.  https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Tolerance_Intervals_for_Normal_Data.pdf clearly uses $z_\alpha$ to refer to a lower quantile, otherwise the formula they cite would not be correct.  I trust this proves my point about needing to be clear about what the notation means.

Comment: No you are right. Barring the normal distribution, old statistical tables only seem to tabulate upper quantiles of distributions like $t,\chi^2$ and $F$.

Comment: @s5s The reason why you are not getting the exact results as you are seeing in the table you included is because the formula you are using to perform the computation for $k$ is an approximation.  Refer to https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/18/help-and-how-to/quality-and-process-improvement/quality-tools/how-to/tolerance-intervals-normal-distribution/methods-and-formulas/methods-and-formulas/ for additional documentation, as well as the reference to NCSS PASS documentation in my previous comment.